# Can a vector boson carry cosmic acceleration?

Tags: cosmology, dark-energy, ghosts

[Clifton, Ferreira, Padilla and Skordis](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1106.2476.pdf) discuss ghosts arising from dark energy:

> To get cosmic acceleration we need an additional repulsive force to
>   act between massive objects at large distances. If this force is to be
>   mediated by a particle of even spin, such as a scalar (spin 0) or a
>   tensor (spin 2), then the kinetic term describing this must have the
>   “wrong” sign, that is, it must be a ghost.

Is there any reason a spin-1 boson cannot mediate dark energy? (Note that the carrier need not match the cosmological parameter's spin, as $\Lambda$ being a scalar does not preclude spin-2 mediation of cosmic acceleration.)